# Загрузка всех частей Form. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

У меня есть главная форма и кусок кода, который загружает внутри главной формы другую форму.
Пример:

```
private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showSubMenu(panel2);
            openChildForm(new Form2());
        }

        private Form activeForm = null;
        private void openChildForm(Form childForm)
        {
            if (activeForm != null)
                activeForm.Close();
            activeForm = childForm;
            childForm.TopLevel = false;
            childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panelChildForm.Controls.Add(childForm);
            panelChildForm.Tag = childForm;
            childForm.BringToFront();
            childForm.Show();
        }
```

Проблема: Если нажать на другую кнопку, которая открывает другую форму и возвратиться к прошлой, то форму приходится загружать заново. 
Как сделать чтобы при загрузке главной форме, другие части тоже загружались?

Comment: для того чтобы не ждать прогрузки данных, которые вы, вероятно, загружаете прямо в коде формы, данные должны жить в модельных классах и объектах и прогружаться/обновляться/и т.д. независимо от окошек приложения. А вообще, у меня встречный вопрос: зачем вы каждый раз создаете новую форму? Если вы по ним можете бегать постоянно, то можно использовать Form.Hide() вместо Form.Close() и состояние окна сохранится. Но для этого перед открытием нужно иметь ссылку на созданную форму, а если создавать каждый раз новую - эффекта не будет, а утечка ресурсов будет.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам необходимо выполнить какой-то код вместе с загрузкой главной формы, вы можете добавить его в конструктор класса.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadDefaultForm();
}
```

Не совсем понятно описана проблема.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что когда нажимаешь на кнопку в списке появляется форма и она загружается (1 шаг). Когда нажимаешь на другую кнопку, то открывается другая форма (2 шаг). И когда повторяешь шаг 1, форму приходится заново загружать, а эта форма сильно нагружена и приходится ждать 5-10 секунд.

Comment: Как уже ответил @rdorn вы можете использовать form.Hide() для скрытия формы, form.Show для её отображения.